# mongodb atlas api Create Legacy Backup Restore Job

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongorestore

I have two clusters A and B in project C.
A uses legacy backup and B uses cloud backup.

I am trying to use mongodb atlas API to create a restore job for A to restore to B.
My cli command look like this:

```
curl --user "<public key>:<private key>" --digest \
     --header "Accept: application/json" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --request POST "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/< C 's project id>/clusters/<A's cluster name>/restoreJobs?pretty=true" \
     --data '
       {
         "delivery" : {
           "methodName" : "AUTOMATED_RESTORE",
           "targetGroupId" : "< C 's project id>",
           "targetClusterId" : "<B's cluster name>"
         },
         "snapshotId": "XXXXX"
       }'
```

I got error like this:

```
{
  "detail" : "Received JSON for the delivery attribute does not match expected format.",
  "error" : 400,
  "errorCode" : "INVALID_JSON_ATTRIBUTE",
  "parameters" : [ "delivery" ],
  "reason" : "Bad Request"
}%
```

this is the reference: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/legacy-backup/restore/create-one-restore-job/

can anyone help with this command? what is incorrect in it?

more details:

1. I run from UI that A can restore to B. it doesn't matter they have different backup settings.
2. from reference example, it said using , its incorrect and output error can't recognize id so I used  instead.
3. someone else also has a similar error I had because of syntax error: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12396, but I cant find there is an error in my command.

Comment: I would ask this via the official support channels.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you are using wrong syntax.

Refer: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/cloud-backup/restore/create-one-restore-job/

```
curl --user "{PUBLIC-KEY}:{PRIVATE-KEY}" --digest --include \
     --header "Accept: application/json" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --request POST "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/{PROJECT-ID}/clusters/{SOURCE-CLUSTER-NAME}/backup/restoreJobs" \
     --data '{
         "snapshotId" : "{SNAPSHOT-ID}",
         "deliveryType" : "automated",
         "targetClusterName" : "{TARGET-CLUSTER-NAME}",
         "targetGroupId" : "{TARGET-PROJECT-ID}"
       }'
```